# Designing the schema for storing, editing and customizing a list

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid, schemaless

I am not very experienced in db design, and have not built something like this before, where it involved creating and managing lists, so any advice is much appreciated. Performance can be tuned later on, much more concerned about maintainability and extendability.

I am using Mongodb, and I allow teachers to create their personal educational syllabus that is made up of individual reusable modules. A teacher can in turn customize the syllabus for different students.

###Option 1: Store numerical sequence in the "joint" table:

```
Syllabus
- has_many SyllabusModuleRecords

SyllabusModuleRecord
- belongs to Syllabus
- belongs to Module
- int Sequence

Module
- has_many SyllabusModuleRecords

s = Syllabus.new
SyllabusModuleRecord.create(:syllabus => s, :module => module1, :sequence =>1 )        
SyllabusModuleRecord.create(:syllabus => s, :module => module2 , :sequence =>2 )
.. and so on
```

To edit it, I pretty much need to reset all the sequences everytime a modification to the program is made.

###Option 2: Store records with a pointer to a before and after

```
s = Syllabus.new
s1 = SyllabusModuleRecord.create(:syllabus => s, :module => module1, :before =>nil )        
s2 = SyllabusModuleRecord.create(:syllabus => s, :module => module2 , :before => s1 )
```

###Option 3: Store module ids as an array inside Syllabus

```
Syllabus
- array of module_ids
```

This is obviously the simplest, but I would not be able to store program/module specific information. also, I need to do my own validation checks.

Another consideration is that I would need to allow teachers to in turn customize the syllabus for students too, something like this:

```
Student
- has_one Syllabus
- has_many SyllabusPersonalizations

SyllabusPersonalizations
- has_one Student
- has_one Syallabus
- .... customization information...
```

Comment: What's your reason for doing this in MongoDB?  Your data seems very relational and might work better in a SQL database

Comment: @Mason i know right? ;) i started using mongodb a while back and never really looked back. The flexibility, ease of changing, no-need for db migrations for adding simple objects and fields really made a huge difference. 

Also, the option for migrating to sql when my requirements are fixed is actually not too bad - I did that once before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Foreword: assumptions forthcoming :)

The relationship you are describing is perfect for the JSON document structure.  Forget the `has_many` and `belongs_to` for this scenario.  Use JSON's ability to nest objects in a arrays.  I would recommend you to quit using a ODM in the short-run while you get your head around MongoDB's expressive documents.

Add the `modules` as needed to a nested array on a syllabus.  Then, allow the teacher to modify the content for that syllabus only.  You would have something like the following for the syllabus:

```
{
  course_id: ObjectId(),
  modules: [
    {
      module_template_id: ObjectId(),
      name: "bla bla bla",
      description: "bla bla bla",
      due_date: "2013-09-28",
      modified_from_template: false
    },
    {
      module_template_id: ObjectId(),
      name: "bla bla",
      description: "bla bla customized",
      due_date: "2013-10-05",
      modified_from_template: true
    }
  ]
}
```

You would have another `module_templates` collection that is the parent

Comment: hey chris! this is great. after thinking about my requirements, etc - i ended up going with somehting very close. Thank you for your inspiration!